# Sharepoint 2013 Service Pack 1 url broken

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Can't download service pack 1.
Page message: We are sorry, the page you requested cannot be found.

I use this [url](http://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=42008).

Tell me please, where i can get SP1 now?
Thanks!

Comment: It seems like the SP1 for both Foundation and Server are down by the moment. I don't like it..

Comment: Links are still down/broken... What is going on there?

Comment: now the sp1 links are up under these links ::::: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42544 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42548

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2850035/en

For foundation this is the link: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=fb1ea5ad-f61f-4a62-9266-073da0a38d2f.

But as you say, right now the links to download are not accessible. I guess you should open a support ticket with Microsoft or hang in there a couple of hours and see

Comment: Where a i can open a support ticket?

Comment: Under assisted support here I guess, you must have an agreement with Microsoft though http://support.microsoft.com/gp/gp_sharepointserver_main/en

Comment: Hmm, this is not good news. What have they done now? :P

Comment: still, not available...

Comment: No, they retracted it yesterday. Found a major bug that could hinder future updates @AlexanderUlmaskulov

Comment: Yes, i know. I wrote 'withdrawn' instead 'retracted'. My English is not very good. Sorry.

Comment: now the sp1 links are on . under this link http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42544 and http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42548

Comment: Yes, now it is called Service Pack 1, Mark 2

Answer (score 0):

User 'IL De' from msdn forum in [this topic](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/98198b9c-fe9c-44aa-900a-4796a53342ef/sp1-sharepoint-2013-?forum=sharepointru) ( at Russian) give answer.

> We recently discovered a problem with this package Service Pack 1 can prevent users from deploying more open or incremental update Service Pack 1. As a precaution, we have been disabled on the download page to the publication of a new package.
>
> Known issue in SharePoint Foundation 2013 SP1 can affect the functionality of the Web search. We recommend limiting the production install SharePoint Foundation 2013 SP1, while the hotfix is ​​available. SharePoint Server 2013 is not affected by this issue.